# NetworkManager GUI: How to affect a VLAN to an Ethernet Connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I'm using Ubuntu Mate and created VLAN are not listed in the Applet Menu.

I would like to know how to affect a VLAN to a specific Ethernet Connection to enable a VLAN when you activate an Ethernet Connection an deactivate it when this Ethernet connection is disabled.

[Ethernet Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJGTC.png)

Here are my network connections:

[Network Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6hiI.png)

I have created a VLAN : `test.2112`

VLAN: VLAN Tab

[VLAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mtXG.png)

VLAN: IPV4 Settings

[VLAN: IPV4 Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmw6n.png)

I have created an Ethernet Connection : `test.2112`

Ethernet Connection: Ethernet Tab

[Ethernet Connection: Ethernet Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nDHg.png)

Ethernet Connection: IPV4 Settings

[Ethernet Connection: IPV4 Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaeHk.png)

If I check "Automatically connect to this network when it is available" for the VLAN under the General Tab this one is always UP.

[VLAN: General Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFN0v.png)

If I uncheck "Automatically connect to this network when it is available" for the VLAN under the General Tab this one is never activated.

I have tried to set the "Parent Interface" option to `enp1s0 (via “test.2112”)` but it seems to have no effect.

[Parent Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkUaA.png)

The two interfaces 
- Ethernet Connection `test.2112`
- VLAN `test.2112`
are active at the same time

> enp1s0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>           inet 10.0.0.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
>           inet6 fe80::a9c1:6593:c4fc:3201  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           ether 30:65:ec:8c:b3:a5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 832104790  bytes 428508362607 (428.5 GB)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 3876  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 1195724290  bytes 1628838882720 (1.6 TB)
>           TX errors 1  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> enp1s0.2112: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>           inet 10.0.0.20  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
>           inet6 fe80::8fa5:673d:e2fb:a045  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           ether 30:65:ec:8c:b3:a5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 87  bytes 11831 (11.8 KB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

I have another coputer with the following IP address : `10.0.0.11 without VLAN`.
I always can ping the other computer.

If I activate another Ethernet Connection as `netgear_wg302` with 192.168.1.0/24 as IP Address, OK I can't no more ping the other computer but the VLAN `test.2112` is always active.

I tried to change the `Method` in the VLAN Settings IPV4 Address tab from `Manual` to `Disabled` or `Local Only` but the VLAN does not work anymore.

Even when all Ethernet Connections are disconnected ... the VLAN is still alive !

So is it possible (without patching NetworkManager) to affect an Ethernet Connection to a dedicated and a specific VLAN with NetworkManager `GUI` and when this Ethernet Connection is activated it is with it's own VLAN and when the Ethernet Connection is disconnected the VLAN is deleted/disconnected and replaced by another one or none depending of the configuration of the newly activated Ethernet Connection ?

Many Thanks for your help.

Kinds Regards